# How to set msi properties from CommandLine when installer is running in silent mode?

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, installshield-2009

I have an application which recieves some settings at the time of installations
the recieved settings are stored in some files for the proper working of the application.

These are done by the custom actions. Each custom action is executed on the various stages of the installation wizard.
And these custom actions sets and retrievs various msi properties. (The values of the properties retrieved by the custom actions are those provided by the user.)

eg:- checking for the valid database, with the values provided by the user.

These are all working correctly with the installer EXE that I have made using 
Installshield 2009

Now I have to make the installer to work in silent mode.

How can I set the MSI properties via commandline?
Currently the Installer is an EXE and not msi.

Do I need to make any changes in the installer part?
Can I do it using the Current EXE?

Any one Please Help.....
Thanks In advance.....

Comment: if you found the correct answer below, please mark it as such.. it helps other users when they have a similar problem as yours identify the correct answer

Answer (score 4):

You can pass parameters from the exe to the msi using /v.

For example, to make the msi print verbose logs, you should run it as:

```
    setup.exe /v"/L*v\"%temp%\install.log\"
```

Similarly, to set msi properties using the exe, you should use:

```
    setup.exe /v"NEWPROP=1"
```

Check out the following for more details:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pcomhelp/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.pcomm.doc%2Fbooks%2Fhtml%2Finstall_guide12.htm

Comment: Hi Thanks a Lot for the answer... and it worked....
But the Problem is that the custom actions are not getting executed in the silent mode installation...
eg:- validating the install location, db etc.
the custom action was written on the behaviour of 'Next'  button in the dialog... I think in silent mode as it doesnot displayed this is not executed...
how can I make to execute these custom actions.
please help.....

Comment: Also 1 more thing I would like to know is, can I set the Custom MSI properties through commandline, it seems that the values given for custom properties, through command line was not set.... is thare any restrictions for setting values for custom properties through commandline..?

Comment: Custom actions which tied to UI are executed only when UI is shown. There are several `*ExecuteSequence` tables in MSI which drive the installation. When UI is shown, actions from [`InstallUISequence`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369543.aspx) are executed; with no UI, this table is skipped, [`InstallExecuteSequence`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369500.aspx) is used. So only setup vendor can fix it.

Comment: Only public MSI properties (_all uppercase_) can be set from the command line. Custom actions can use non-public properties.